# R plot.window error (...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Tags: r

I need to do a scatterplot of a dataset that contains character, integer and numeric attributes.

Here is my code:

```r
fdn <- read.table("final-data-train.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
pairs(~dtj+qh+sci+bw+is,data=fdn,row1attop=FALSE,subset=response,main="Fund Data")
```

Data Structure:

```r
str(fnlDat_Train)
'data.frame':   30994 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ response: chr  "N" "N" "Y" "Y" ...
 $ id      : int  165931 241964 387089 433922 175120 353214 458159 512275 310008 91571 ...
 $ wc      : chr  "d" "b" "b" "b" ...
 $ zwp     : chr  "R" "S" "O" "Q" ...
 $ wi      : chr  "gnq" "gmz" "gmz" "gmz" ...
 $ dtj     : num  3.32 0 3.46 3.32 3.74 ...
 $ bnf     : chr  "J" "K" "J" "L" ...
 $ qh      : num  1.62 1.47 2.01 1.92 1.74 ...
 $ ent     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ sci     : num  1.36 1.42 1.43 1.41 1.36 ...
 $ ypz     : int  11 11 14 10 1 0 1 1 14 1 ...
 $ bw      : num  0.316 0.447 0.447 0.387 0.316 ...
 $ tdt     : chr  "kc" "sm" "zp" "sm" ...
 $ sb      : chr  "s2" "s2" "s2" "s2" ...
 $ ox      : chr  "bf" "fy" "ix" "bf" ...
 $ xt      : chr  "fcc" "ntb" "ntb" "ntb" ...
 $ np      : chr  "j" "j" "j" "k" ...
 $ ku      : chr  "y" "v" "u" "x" ...
 $ is      : num  0.241 3.762 2.5 2.477 4.171 ..
```

I received an error code:

**Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf**

How can I plot a scatterplot for a dataset with different kinds of attributes?

Comment: `response` is not logical so `subset=response` seems pretty risky. Did you mean to select "Y" or "N"?

Comment: Did you mean I should subset all character variable? subset=c(response,wc,zwp....)?

Comment: No. I thought you should either leave it out or say what you’re trying to do with it. (You clearly don’t understand how to use that parameter properly. )